# get post values through steps in checkout file cs-cart

Tags: cs-cart

I am in the checkout page on cs-cart (version 4.1.2) I have opened the firebug to see what variables are sending through pages 3 to 4.
In the post tab, I saw this variable: shipping_ids[0] = 3
How can I take this variable in the step 4, which it is the payment methods?

I tried lots of things, but still no luck!

{$smarty.post.shipping_ids} or ..get..

*In the 3 step, I have 5 options, so client could choose one of them. So I have also tried to get the value through javascript... still nothing... maybe I forget something or did something wrong..

Could anyone guide me or share any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
{foreach from=$cart.shipping key="id" item="shipping"}
    {$id} {*shipping id*}
    {$shipping.shipping} {*shipping name*}
{/foreach}
```

You should probably debug the controller instead, as this is where all the variables come from. Take a look at `checkout.php` controller. Look for `$view->assign` calls.

**Update:**
I have updated the code above. Notice that the key of the `$cart.shipping` array is actually the id of the shipping.

Comment: the variable $shipping.shipping is the name of the shipping methods you have entered, for example Fedex e.t.c....as you said correctly!
The one I was looking for is $shipping.shipping_id which it is a number, so I could check {if $shippin.shipping_id == 3} (or whatever)
///do this
{else}
//do this

It was so easy, and I could not find it. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Edited my answer to get the id of the shipping. Hope it helps you!